# Show each unique name against each unique ID - partition over?

Tags: sql, partition

I've mocked up below how my data looks:

```
Job_ID    Employee
1         Tim
1         John
1         Tim
2         Dave
```

and I want to return:

```
Job_ID    Employee
1         Tim
1         John
2         Dave
```

where Job ID 1 now has two entries because there are two employees on the job.

I was hoping this could be achievable via a PARTITION BY:

```
SELECT job_id, employee OVER (PARTITION BY employee)
   from data
```

But I think I'm misunderstanding how to use it in this instance?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could just use `GROUP BY`:

```
SELECT job_id, employee
FROM data
GROUP BY job_id, employee
```

Or even just a `SELECT DISTINCT`:

```
SELECT DISTINCT job_id, employee
FROM data
```

Comment: Simple. Should have got that!

Answer (score 2):

## Simple solution:

```
select distinct job_id, employee 
from emp_job 
order by job_id, employee ;
```

## Partitioning:

```
select d1.job_id, d1.employee 
from 
  (SELECT job_id, employee, 
          row_number() OVER (partition by job_id, employee 
                             order by employee) as rnk 
   from data
)d1
where d1.rnk = 1
```

Partitioning In Teradata:

```
SELECT job_id, employee 
from emp_job 
qualify row_number() OVER (partition by job_id, employee 
                           order by data) = 1;
```